# Security of sessions in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, session, session-variables

If I do the following in one of my .aspx pages:

```
Session["MySess123"] = "Some plain text";
```

and then read it from another .ashx page:

```
string str = Session["MySess123"].ToString();
```

Will `Some plain text` in any way be visible in a client browser?

Or in other words, how easy for an "intruder" is it to get access to my session variables?

PS. I am not storing any sensitive information this way. I use it for the purpose of storing [Captchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you certainly know, sessions are stored on server. So it's the best way to transfer "sensitive" data.
ViewBag, hidden fields and cookies are stored on client side so it's not good at all. Session stay the best solution.
But if anybody reach your server, he can access all these variables.

It's not very well secured but you can add a basic encryption or something like this if you want to.